# How to filter an ordered table until the first row where a threshold is reached?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm using PostgreSQL and I have a `table` with the following columns: `id`, `distance`, and `length`. I want to order the table by `distance` and create a new column called `cum_length` using a window function. I also want to filter the rows so that only rows until `cum_length` value cross a certain threshold are included in the final result.

Example of input `table`:

| id | distance | length |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 1 |
| 2 | 5 | 2 |
| 3 | 8 | 1 |
| 4 | 1 | 3 |
| 5 | 3 | 2 |
| 6 | 9 | 2 |

Desired output for a threshold of `6`:

| id | distance | length | cum_length |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 1 | 3 | 3 |
| 5 | 3 | 2 | 5 |
| 2 | 5 | 2 | 7 |

This is the SQL that I came up with:

```sql
WITH ordered_table AS (
  SELECT id,
    distance,
    length,
    SUM(length) OVER (ORDER BY distance) AS cum_length
  FROM table)
SELECT *
FROM ordered_table
WHERE cum_length <= 6
```

But this omits the last row of the desired result.

Comment: Why do you expect a cum_length = 7 in the desired output if the threshold is 6?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name the threshold is a minimum. I need `cum_length` to cross the threshold, but I need just the first row after that.

Comment: Well, if it's a minimum shouldn't you use `>= 6` then?

Comment: It's really hard to communicate this clearly...  I want all rows until I have at least the threshold, not less.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
WITH ordered_table AS 
(
  SELECT id, distance, length,
    SUM(length) OVER (ORDER BY distance) AS cum_length
  FROM table_name
)
SELECT id, distance, length, cum_length
FROM ordered_table
WHERE cum_length <= COALESCE((SELECT MIN(cum_length) FROM ordered_table WHERE cum_length > 6), 6)
```

For your sample data, this is equivalent to `WHERE cum_length <= 7`.

[See demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/D_ALu67q)

Answer (score 1):

Here is it based on your `ordered_table` query and an extra `lag` window function to calculate `previous_is_less` than the threshold value. Records where `previous_is_less` is true or null qualify for selection.

```sql
with t as 
(
 select *, 
    lag(cum_length) over (order by cum_length) < 6 as previous_is_less
 from  
 (
  SELECT id, distance, length,
     SUM(length) OVER (order BY distance) AS cum_length
  from the_table
 ) as ordered_table
)
select id, distance, length, cum_length
from t 
where coalesce(previous_is_less, true)
order by cum_length;
```

DB-Fiddle [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8xzMQsiabHoJNmqv1btgaB/2)

Answer (score 0):

May be interesting to compare with this one on large data set, only one sorting by distance and should stop scanning data as soon as the threshold is found

```
with data(id, distance, length) as (
    select 1, 10, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    select 2, 5, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    select 3, 8, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    select 4, 1, 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    select 5, 3, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    select 6, 9, 2 FROM DUAL -- UNION ALL
),
rdata(id, distance, length, rn) as (
    select id, distance, length, row_number() over(order by distance) as rn
    from data 
),
recdata(id, distance, length, rn, cumlength) as ( 
    select id, distance, length, rn, length
    from rdata d
    where rn = 1
    
    union all
    
    select d.id, d.distance, d.length, d.rn, d.length + r.cumlength
    from recdata r
    join rdata d on d.rn = r.rn + 1 and r.cumlength <= 6 
)
select id, distance, length, cumlength from recdata
;
```